# [React-Native]: No Android device or emulator connected

Tags: android, react-native

I've created a react application with the command **npx react-native init**. it worked well. I can deploy this app on an Android Emulator, but cannot do it on my device. The device is in developer mode and when I run the command **adb devices** it returns the device connected as follows:

[image]

But, when I try to run the **npx react-native run-android** command, it responds that an **No Android device or emulator connected**.

[image]

Does anyone has been through something like this? I don't know what to do

Comment: Simply "Wipe data" to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you enabled USB Debugging

Comment: I managed to connect an actual device using USB. Tried

sudo adb kill-server 
sudo adb start-server

Comment: Try disabling and re-enabling USB debugging

Comment: any solution @WillRock?

Answer (score -1):

take a backup or delete your created emulators from the location c:/users/username/.android/avd and run react-native run-android. It worked for me.